# How to set GtkSpinButton margin in GTK2?

Tags: c, widget, margin, gtk3, gtk2

I'm working on GtkSpinButton (GTK2/GTK3) to make another control. (DateTime).

As part of the task, I need to add a button 'next to' the GtkSpinButton to influence the content in GtkSpinButton. (when you click it, a calendar pops out). 
However, when I add a button next to the control, it is not visible or parts of it are cut off.

To solve this in GTK3, I added margin on the right:

```
   gtk_widget_set_margin_end(.., buttonSize)   @since 3.12 
   gtk_widget_set_margin_right(.., buttonSize) @since 3.0
```

This works nicely.
However, I'm struggling to find something equivalent in gtk2.

Is there a margin in gtk2?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in GTK2 is [`GtkAlignment`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkAlignment.html) and its various padding properties.